# Qt5 Run task in background

Tags: c++11, asynchronous, qt5

I'm working on a Qt5 application where I need to perform some tasks asynchronously. I need something similar to `dispatch_async` in Objective-C. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt provides [QtConcurrent::run](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtconcurrent.html#run)

C++11 provides [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)